# YAML Exception . Invalid Yaml

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload my Django rest framework application in AWS elasticbeanstalk. I followed the steps from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

I did exactly what is mentioned there and ended up in an error on creating environment.

```
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-989c-171129_120334".
Uploading TestApi/app-989c-171129_120334.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - The configuration file .ebextensions/packag
s.config in application version app-989c-171129_120334 contains invalid YAML or
JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning for the next token
found character         '\t' that cannot start any token
 in "<reader>", line 6, column 1:

    ^
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (p) at position 0.. Update
the configuration file.
```

My files contains exactly same info as mentioned in the docs.
**.ebextensions\django.config :-**

```
 option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
```

Where am I going wrong ?

**UPDATE:-**

```
(env) C:\Users\india\Desktop\tutorial\env>eb init -p python2.7 TestApi

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
14) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
15) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
(default is 3):
Application TestApi has been created.

(env) C:\Users\india\Desktop\tutorial\env>eb init
Note: Elastic Beanstalk now supports AWS CodeCommit; a fully-managed source cont
rol service. To learn more, see Docs: https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/
Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (y/N) (default is n): y

Select a repository
1) codecommit-origin
2) [ Create new Repository ]
(default is 1):
(env) C:\Users\india\Desktop\tutorial\env>eb create djang0-api-env
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-989c-171129_111635".
Uploading TestApi/app-989c-171129_111635.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: djang0-api-env
  Application name: TestApi
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-989c-171129_111635
  Environment ID: e-89wz2qwskj
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Python 2.7 running on 6
4bit Amazon Linux/2.6.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2017-11-29 05:46:52.690000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-957209152698 as Amazon S3 storage bucket
for environment data.
ERROR: The configuration file .ebextensions/packages.config in application versi
on app-989c-171129_111635 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid
 Yaml: while scanning for the next token
found character         '\t' that cannot start any token
 in "<reader>", line 6, column 1:

    ^
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (p) at position 0.. Update
the configuration file.
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to launch environment.
```

Comment: Use a YAML validator like [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/)

Comment: @ChackoMathew It is valid and have to be . It is same as in aws doc

Comment: Did you copy any tabs/spaces with it, can you share the entire snippet as you have it in your question?

Comment: @jarnohenneman I am pretty sure in this I haven't copy any tabs/spaces. I had updated the command flow .

Comment: The error is saying that on line 6, the first character is a tab where it should only be spaces.

Comment: @jarnohenneman I have no file as packages.config. I have a single file name django.config which include only three line `option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py`